# WP_Query extended with AJAX

Tags: posts, wp-query, ajax

Im using the wp_query with ajax to display and filter my custom post.

everything works fine until i try to use my extended version of wp_query in the args parameters.

my js file code:

```
jQuery(function($){
$('#filter').submit(function(){
    var filter = $('#filter');
    $.ajax({
        url:filter.attr('action'),
        data:filter.serialize(), // form data
        type:filter.attr('method'), // POST
        beforeSend:function(xhr){
            filter.find('button').text('Processing...'); // changing the button label
        },
        success:function(data){
            filter.find('button').text('Apply filter'); // changing the button label back
            $('#response').html(data); // insert data
        }
    });
    return false;
});});
```

the php part with args:

```
    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'rides',
     'geo_query' => array( 
            'latfrom'      => '45.7579341',
            'lngfrom'      => '4.7650812', 
            'latto'      => '26.123555',
            'lngto'      => '6.5445445', 
            'distancefrom' => 10,
            'distanceto' => 10,
            'compare'  => '<='
            ),
);
```

the loop:

```
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

if( $query->have_posts() ) :
    while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post();
        echo '<h2>' . $query->post->post_title . '</h2>';
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
else :
    echo 'No posts found';
endif;

die();
}
```

As you can see, I am using the custom geo_query parameter, which is an extension of the wp_query. This does work when using the standard wp_query BUT NOT when using it with ajax...

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: How is it not working? What is the response you are receiving? How are you calling your wp_query in the ajax call?

Comment: All the custom posts "rides" are displayed as a response...so filtering is not working.

Comment: How are you defining `geo_query`

Comment: Can you add more of your server code that is called from AJAX?

Comment: I have added all my code below and above.. really i have tried everything.. can't find the issue. The geo_query extension works fine when using the classic wp_query method.. but not when using ajax :(

Comment: Have you tried a `var_dump` of $query to see what SQL is executing? Are you using `wp_ajax_function`?

Answer (score 0):

this is my geo_query extension of wp_query:

```
add_filter( 'posts_fields', 'willy_geo_fields', 10, 2 );
function willy_geo_fields( $fields, $q ) {
if ( isset( 
      $q->query_vars['geo_query']['latfrom'],
      $q->query_vars['geo_query']['lngfrom'],
      $q->query_vars['geo_query']['latto'],
      $q->query_vars['geo_query']['lngto'],
      $q->query_vars['geo_query']['distancefrom'],
      $q->query_vars['geo_query']['distanceto']

      ) ) {

    global $wpdb;
    $fields .= $wpdb->prepare(", ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians( %f ) ) 
                    * cos( radians( metalatfrom.meta_value ) ) 
                    * cos( radians( metalngfrom.meta_value ) -     radians( %f ) ) 
                    + sin( radians( %f ) ) 
                    * sin( radians( metalatfrom.meta_value ) ) ) ) AS distancefrom
                    , ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians( %f ) ) 
                    * cos( radians( metalatto.meta_value ) ) 
                    * cos( radians( metalngto.meta_value ) - radians( %f ) ) 
                    + sin( radians( %f ) ) 
                    * sin( radians( metalatto.meta_value ) ) ) ) AS distanceto
    ",
                  $q->query_vars['geo_query']['latfrom'],
                  $q->query_vars['geo_query']['lngfrom'],
                  $q->query_vars['geo_query']['latfrom'],
                  $q->query_vars['geo_query']['latto'],
                  $q->query_vars['geo_query']['lngto'],
                  $q->query_vars['geo_query']['latto'] );
}
return $fields;
}
  add_filter( 'posts_join', 'willy_geo_join', 10, 2 );
  function willy_geo_join( $join, $q) {
if ( isset( 
      $q->query_vars['geo_query']['latfrom'],
      $q->query_vars['geo_query']['lngfrom'],
      $q->query_vars['geo_query']['distancefrom'],
      $q->query_vars['geo_query']['lngto'],
      $q->query_vars['geo_query']['lngto'],
      $q->query_vars['geo_query']['distanceto'] ) ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $join .= " INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta AS metalatfrom ON ( $wpdb->posts.ID = metalatfrom.post_id )";
    $join .= " INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta AS metalngfrom ON ( $wpdb->posts.ID = metalngfrom.post_id )";
    $join .= " INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta AS metalatto ON ( $wpdb->posts.ID = metalatto.post_id )";
    $join .= " INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta AS metalngto ON ( $wpdb->posts.ID = metalngto.post_id )";
 }
 return $join;
 }
    add_filter( 'posts_where', 'willy_geo_where', 10, 2 );
   function willy_geo_where( $where, $q ) {
    if ( isset( 
      $q->query_vars['geo_query']['latfrom'],
      $q->query_vars['geo_query']['lngfrom'],
      $q->query_vars['geo_query']['distancefrom'],
      $q->query_vars['geo_query']['latto'],
      $q->query_vars['geo_query']['lngto'],
      $q->query_vars['geo_query']['distanceto'] ) ) {

    global $wpdb;
    $where .= " AND metalatfrom.meta_key = 'latfrom'";
    $where .= " AND metalngfrom.meta_key = 'lngfrom'";
    $where .= " AND metalatto.meta_key = 'latto'";
    $where .= " AND metalngto.meta_key = 'lngto'";
 }
 return $where;
 }
add_filter( 'posts_groupby', 'willy_geo_distance', 10, 2 );
function willy_geo_distance( $groupby, $q ) {
if ( isset( 
     $q->query_vars['geo_query']['latfrom'],
      $q->query_vars['geo_query']['lngfrom'],
      $q->query_vars['geo_query']['distancefrom'],
      $q->query_vars['geo_query']['latto'],
      $q->query_vars['geo_query']['lngto'],
      $q->query_vars['geo_query']['distanceto'] ) ) {

    $compare = '<=';
    if ( isset( $q->query_vars['geo_query']['compare'] )
      && in_array( $q->query_vars['geo_query']['compare'], array( '<', '<=', '>', '>=' ) ) ) {
        $compare = $q->query_vars['geo_query']['compare'];
    }
    global $wpdb;
    $groupby .= $wpdb->prepare( "$wpdb->posts.ID HAVING distancefrom <= %d AND distanceto <= %d ",
                  $q->query_vars['geo_query']['distancefrom'],
                  $q->query_vars['geo_query']['distanceto'] );
}
return false;
 }
```